# Nodejs Addon - passing regex string to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I am trying to figure out how to create a regular expression in C++. I want to turn a string passed from JavaScript to C++ into a regular expression.

I have this:

```
std::regex re;

  if (!args[1]->IsString()) {
    Nan::ThrowTypeError("Second argument to 'replace-line' must be a string regular expression.");
    return;
  }
  else{
    v8::String::Utf8Value regexin(args[1]->ToString());
    re(*regexin);
  }
```

but this fails to compile, with this error:

```
../hello.cpp: In function ‘void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
../hello.cpp:50:16: error: no match for call to ‘(regex_t {aka re_pattern_buffer}) (char*)’
     re(*regexin);
```

anybody know how I can declare/create a `regex` given this `v8::String`?

Comment: It does compile for me (node 7.0.0, cmake-js 3.3.1). Also, `regexin(val.As<v8::RegExp>()->GetSource())` is maybe more expressive

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but maybe you have just declared regexin, but not initialized it? Have you tried doing `V8... regexin = new V8... (args...)`?